# How do you addFacetRefinement with multiple values in Algolia?

Tags: algolia

I have a list of places: [A, B, C];

A user can create an item and associate a place to it:
`item1 > place: A`

The user can search for a place and get the items:

`this.algoliaService.helper.addFacetRefinement('place', A);`

All this works as expected, my question is:

How can I setup the creation of the item so it is associated with all the places ?
So a user picks a "ALL places" and any place search would have this item in the results?

Is there a way to add "All Places" in Algolia?

`this.algoliaService.helper.addFacetRefinement('place', A,B,C);`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 possibilities:

1. in your snippet, you are listing some places; if you want to allow searching in any of the facet values, then you can do what we call "[disjunctive faceting](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/concepts.html#disjunctive-faceting)" (basically, this does an "OR" on the facet values so would return all objects that have at least one of the values in their record). We have some code snippets for [js](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/examples.html#disjunctive-facet-list) or [mobile](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/full-text-search/filtering-faceting/swift/#disjunctive-faceting) clients.
2. in case you don't want to provide an exhaustive list of values, you'd have to add another boolean field like `has_place` and filter on this field